# how to use prevent default and toggle inside a function?

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I'm trying to build a library where the user can write the info and the book and add it to the library. I created a modal form where the user can write the info and submit it.

This is the modal html

```
<form class="modal__container">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal__content">
            <label for="">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" id="title"> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal__content">
            <label for="">Author:</label>
            <input type="text" id="author">
        </div>
        <div class="modal__content">
            <label for="">Pages:</label>
            <input type="number" id="pages">
        </div>
        <label for="">Have you read it?</label>
        <div>
            <label for="yes">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name ="read" value="yes">
            <label for="no">No</label>
            <input type="radio" name ="read" value="no">
        </div>
        
        <button class="add__book">Add</button>
        <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the function that closes the modal when clicking on the cancel button

```
function toggle() {
    addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        const cancel = document.querySelector(".cancel");
        cancel.addEventListener("click", () => {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        })
    })
}
toggle();
```

Here I have the constructor and the array to store the books

```
let myLibrary = [];

function Book(title, author, pages) {
    this.title = title,
    this.author = author,
    this.pages = pages
}
```

Now I want to create a function that submits the new book

```
submitBook.addEventListener("click", addBookToLibrary);

function addBookToLibrary() {

   let bookTitle = modalTitle.value;
   let bookAuthor = modalAuthor.value;
   let bookPages = modalPages.value;

   let book = new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPages);
   myLibrary.push(book);

   console.log(bookTitle)
   console.log(bookAuthor)
   console.log(bookPages)
   toggle();

}
```

I see the info for half a second and then it disappears. I know I should use prevent default somewhere. I tried this

```
function addBookToLibrary(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   let bookTitle = modalTitle.value;
   let bookAuthor = modalAuthor.value;
   let bookPages = modalPages.value;

   let book = new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPages);
   myLibrary.push(book);

   console.log(bookTitle)
   console.log(bookAuthor)
   console.log(bookPages)
   toggle();

}
```

It displays the info correctly but it doesn't close the modal. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you show your modal html code?

Comment: You don't want to add a listener every time you call toggle. Define a method called toggle whose body is the body of the listener you have now,  set up your listeners so that they call toggle, and then call toggle how you are inside of the form submit.

Comment: make a close() func and split out the code which is in toggle()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have an anonymous function that does what you want: close the modal.  It's inside another anonymous function which opens the modal:

```
 addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    const cancel = document.querySelector(".cancel");
    cancel.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    });
});
```

You can "refactor" out two named functions from that code, like so:

```
 const hideModal = () => {
    modal.style.display = "none";
 };
 const showModal = () => {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    const cancel = document.querySelector(".cancel");
    cancel.addEventListener("click", hideModal);
 };
 addBtn.addEventListener("click", showModal);
```

Then, inside your other event handlers, you can call either function:

```
function addBookToLibrary() {
  // ...
  hideModal();
}
```